# Interpolation of pixel color in an image, matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a simple question. I have image A and I want to interpolate its rgb to subpixel level.

```
rgb = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');    
red = rgb(:,:,1); % Red channel
green = rgb(:,:,2); % Green channel
blue = rgb(:,:,3); % Blue channel
```

One way to do it is to splitt it into three channels and then do interpolation for every channel. 
  Here I have confusuion. How can I assign rows and colums.I 'm using interp2.

```
Red_subpixel = interp2(X,Y,red,Xq,Yq)
```

What are values of X,Y. What is their expression in matlab code.

Is there any other function that interpolates  all channels alltogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `X` and `Y` you can use `meshgrid`:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(red,1), 1:size(red,2))
```

To see what it does try `[x,y] = meshgrid(1:3,1:3)` in the command line and it should be fairly apparent.